# Error in Parent-Child relationship : The source attribute of the level is marked as 'Parent'

Tags: sql, ssas, parent-child, dimensions

I am trying to define a parent-child relationship in my SSAS project. The dimension is "employee" with a parent being "supervisor". The source of my data was automatically imported from a .bak file given by my professor, though I feel like maybe it was somehow corrupeted or I'm doing something wrong.

The error that I am getting during processing:

```
Level [Sprzedawca].[Subordinate Hierarchy].[Supervisor] : The source attribute of the level is marked as 'Parent'
```

I set the supervisor's attribute usage to "parent". Column names for Id Sprzedawcy (Seller id) and supervisor are both "ImieiNazwisko" (NameAndSurname) which is an attribute that is in the source data, but wasn't automatically moved to attributes (left column) - I'm not sure if I am supposed to drag it there? Anyhow, this does not help either...

[image: View of Sprzedawca (Seller) Dimension]
[image: View of the processed cube]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent-child hierarchy is automatically created when you set attribute usage to the parents of an attribute and ones marked as parent the attribute cannot be used as a level in a user defined hierarchy.

So to resolve your problem, you just need to remove the hierarchy that you have created "Subordinate hierarchy" and things will work perfectly.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your answer. In the instruction we got from the professor, both setting the attribute usage to parent AND adding it as a level in user defined hierarchy were present. As I was searching for the solution, I actually deleted this hierarchy and I could process the cube. Thanks for explanation, now everything is clear!